# Image Manipulation/Processing

Tags: image-processing, png

Google has this 1 whole png image.

[image]

They were able to separate it piece by piece and made it into this:

[image]

But when I tried looking at the source image, what I got was the whole image at the top.

What did they use to manipulate/cut the image and place it into the order above? (Well it doesn't have to be exactly what they used.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google "sprites" that should get you all you need